# Tomcat webapps disappear after Tomcat restart

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running Tomcat 4.1 (client needs it) and the webapps are already installed/exploded in the webapps folder. I use the install webapp via directory to get it into Tomcat Manager and everything is working perfectly.

However when I restart Tomcat the webapps are gone from Tomcat Manager.

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was the fact that inside the applications `.xml` file inside `Tomcat\webapps\` the following line was pointing to the wrong application location:

```
docBase="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 4.1\server\webapps\corepath"
```

Fixing that parameter to point to an actual location on the machine fixed the issue. Now on Tomcat start all applications are loaded back into Tomcat.